# How does whatsapp show message delivered to other recipient (double v icon), in case app is terminated by user

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background, whatsapp

I have tested the following scenario many times on whats app / FB messenger:

1- Terminate the app by swiping.

2- Go to app settings and turn off both notifications and app refresh.

3- send message from other device.

In each time you will get (vv) which means received by other recipient. i have checked and it's delivered in background.

So how whatsapp is handling this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably PushKit notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhatsApp App has VoIP functionality and it uses the VoIP facility to push silent notifications and launch app in background even if "Background App Refresh" and "Push Notification" disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and then send info to your server when user received notification.

Comment: As i mentioned above, turn off notification from settings, so didReceiveRemoteNotification will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

When a push notification message is received `didReceiveRemoteNotification` can be used to inform that the message has received.

So does disabling push notification from settings stops the delivering message indicator?

No, as WhatsApp is using the silent push notification to wake up the App.
However, silent push notification only works when the App in the foreground or if the App has the VOIP capability.
Which is present in the WhatsApp.

So when you disable the push notification from the settings, the silent push notification wakes up the App and use `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to inform of message delivery.